# Why after defining variable and while accessing ,its not showing garbage value in C?

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

When after only defining any number of variables in a source code and trying to print it without initializing it.I am getting the values zero for the last two variables and one or two some other variables.The Last two variables is like blindly(at least to me) we can say like it is declared to zero.

As I am defining the variable inside the function the storage class is defaultly auto and its value is garbage value in this case why is it showing zero for the last two variables every time and for some other variables which is zero is not changing after multiple execution.

**NOTE**

1.If I take the last two zero values and other variables with zeroes as as garbage then why is the zeroes not changing after executions whereas other values are changing after executions.

2.Anyways the last two variable with any number of variables defined is gonna be zero.Why this is only happening with the last two variables.

3.This is not only happening with online compiler I have tried with vs code using gcc compiler in Windows 8 and Linux(pop Os) as the C program is platform dependent.

**Same is in Case with CPP**

[First Execution Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKWtc.png)

[Second Execution Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu399.png)

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int a,b,c,d,e,f;
   printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t",a,b,c,d,e,f);
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any logic behind the execution.Somebody please explain.Thank you.

Comment: And why are you posting code as images?  Post it as text, please.

Comment: You're not guaranteed to get random number garbage on uninitialized variables. All you can conclude is that you can't and shouldn't assume anything about their value. They could be zero. They could be nonsense. They could be zero most of the time but some other value in rare cases.

They simply use registers that may or may not have been used for something else previously, and it could very well be that the last two variables happen to use storage that had zeros previously.

Comment: Strongly disagree this is a duplicate of the linked question. Yes, it is important for the OP to understand what UB is. But the linked question/answer does not actually tell you that an uninitialized read _is_ UB

Comment: It also does not answer the more specific question in this post: 'Why does this incorrect program have this specific behaviour?'. Some say that question is not worth asking since UB is UB, but I disagree. You probably _do_ have an idea what is likely to happen _on your system_ for common UBs such as Nullpointer-dereference. The OP expects garbage values on his incorrect program, which is a way in which uninitialized reads can manifest, but the UB has a different manifestation, that points to real facts of modern Operating systems that C-programmers of those systems should know.

Comment: Knowing which symptoms are typical causes of which UB is important for debugging. For example, what do you look for when you get a segfault? C-programmers have answers, but they are not and cannot be in the standard. C-programming is about more than the standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize a variable and use its value, it will result in **undefined behavior**. For example,

```
int i; //i has not been initialized and so holds garbage value
printf("%d\n",i);//this will lead to undefined behavior.
```

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: If I define 2 variables print the values without initializing and getting two zeroes.Does that mean undefined behavior ?please explain it briefly.

Comment: @JCSubanesh Yes if you use *any* *uninitialized* variable then it will lead to Undefined behavior. It doesn't matter what output you get. Never rely on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

Comment: Lets say If an interviewer asks me to explain the auto storage class concept with its default value.Could you please tell how to explain it with example

Comment: @JCSubanesh Sure but for that you should ask a separate question so that the intent of this current question and your new question don't get mixed up. Also, can you mark my answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: The auto storage class doesn't have a default value. The value is indeterminate until you explicitly write a value to it. There happens to be far more `0` values floating around (from the previous memory usage) than the more obviously 'garbage' values.

Comment: @JCSubanesh To avoid these problems just initialize the variables for built in types irrespective of the fact that whether or not you're using `auto`.